# google map android - factors affecting battery use with location tracking

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location, battery, android-googleapiclient

I have a service which tracks the user's location all the time (as long as its running) and puts the data into a SQL table, and when the app is in the foreground -> the service also sends updates to the UI with the location and the map and location are updated.

1. **When app is in foreground** -> request the location with **high accuracy
   and frequent updates** so the user can enjoy the high accuracy and
   frequent updates in the UI.
2. **When app is closed (only service
   running)** -> request a **less-accurate-location** updates, so I don't
   consume too much battery, because all I do is fill a table.

So, what are the factors affecting battery use when tracking the location?

In the docs sample

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); 
}
```

They say that

> The priority of PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, combined with the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission setting that you've defined in the app manifest, and a fast update interval of 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds), causes the fused location provider to return location updates that are accurate to within a few feet.

So, this is what I would use when the app is in the foreground (in the settings I can see the app has a **"high battery use"** with the location).

but what parameters should I change when **only** the service is running? I want the location using will be saying: **"low battery use"**.